# Export all columns of kendo grid to pdf with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, export-to-pdf

I have 25 columns in kendo grid and want all columns to be exported in pdf.
But it is exporting only 8 to 10 columns, not all.

Here is my Code,

```
pdf = {
          fileName: "My Document.pdf",
          paperSize: "A4",
          allPages: true,
          landscape: true,
          scale: 0.5
       };
```

is there any property which I am missing here ? How do I do it.

One more question,
If I export till 100 records, it is exporting to pdf smoothly, if more than it, it is taking time.

One of my grid has over 100k data. It is not exporting that grid, keeps loading, no error, no success.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words & sayings here. This is not just for Indians.

Comment: do you mean angular or angularjs? they arent the same

Answer (score 0):

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/
check this link you will find somehting.
It will take time to export 10k rows in pdf so its better to export less rows for better performance

Comment: It would be useful to provide a summary here of what it is that the link contains and how it might be helpful.

Comment: I dont knw what way u r approaching and kendo provide its export to pdf module u can find in above link.
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export @progress/kendo-drawing..

Comment: as per limitation of column it is due to page A4 u r using. All 25 columns cannot be generated on a single pdf page for that u have to use next page for other columns or u can use A3 page size

Comment: You should add your previous two comments' contents to your answer. Click "edit" beneath your answer and then go ahead and add the content there.